# How to stop Log4j2 from generating empty log file when the corresponding RollingFileAppender is programitically removed from LoggerConfig?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

In my application I have to keep or remove an RollingFileAppender based on certain condition. Below is my log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration><Appenders>
    <Console name="LogToConsole">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %5p %-50c{2} - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
 <RollingFile name="LogToProfileRollingFile" fileName="${sys:DD_HOME}\logs\DDD\extract\server\Server-${sys:ddd.jvm.startTime}-Profile-log4j.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:DD_HOME}\logs\DDD\extract\server\Server-${sys:ddd.jvm.startTime}-Profile-log4j.log.%i">
               <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>[%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}{}] [%t] %-5p %-50c{2}- %m%n</Pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>              
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50KB"/>                
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
    </RollingFile>      
    <RollingFile name="LogToRollingFile" fileName="${sys:DD_HOME}\logs\DDD\extract\server\Server-${sys:DDD.jvm.startTime}-log4j.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:DD_HOME}\logs\DDD\extract\server\Server-${sys:ddd.jvm.startTime}-log4j.log.%i">
              <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>[%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}{}] [%t] %-5p %-50c{2}- %m%n</Pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>              
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50KB"/>                
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
    </RollingFile>      
</Appenders>    

<Loggers>        
    <Logger name="com.project.log.profile" level="INFO"
        additivity="false">
        <Appender-ref ref="LogToConsole"/>
        <Appender-ref ref="LogToProfileRollingFile"/>
        <Appender-ref ref="LogToRollingFile"/>         
    </Logger>
     <Root level="info">
          <Appender-ref ref="LogToConsole"/>              
          <Appender-ref ref="LogToRollingFile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>    </Configuration>
```

Removed the LogToRollingFile appender programmatically in the following way -

```
LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
        Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = configuration.getLoggerConfig("com.project.log.profile");
        if (loggerConfig.getName().equals("com.project.log.profile")) {
            loggerConfig.removeAppender("LogToProfileRollingFile");
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("There was no logger " + "loggerName");
        }
        context.updateLoggers();
```

Now, after successfully removing the LogToProfileRollingFile Appender, the logs are not getting printed on ${sys:ddd.jvm.startTime}-Profile-log4j.log, but the empty file is getting created. So, below are my questions

- How to stop this empty ${sys:ddd.jvm.startTime}-Profile-log4j.log file from getting created
- Also, how to evaluate and replace environment variables in the log file name. It is working for system propertis(like here I have set **ddd.jvm.startTime** as system property and evaluating it with sys:). But if I set it as an user or system environment variable, I am not able to get it through env:

Comment: Does anyone have any answer to this question, still stuck on these two issues.